# using AND in visual force Page

Tags: visualforce

Is this correct way to join two conditions

```
{!(LEN(editErrorString) > 0 && (zipCodeEdit == zipCodeMap[zipCode])) }
```

Comment: (I seem to remember a "function call syntax": `AND(<c1>, <c2>)`.)

Comment: Have you tried "Googling", have you tried visiting https://salesforce.stackexchange.com?